# How to store a link and open that link with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The plan is to:

1. Open page.
2. Select and store the link class.
3. Open the stored link.

Here is what I got so far.

```
    driver.get("http://www.example.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.className("button-class"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store it as a webelement,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("button-class"));
```

and you can click on that element when you want to

```
element.click();
```

Or If you just wanna store the link,

```
String linkToOpen= driver.findElement(By.className("button-class")).getAttribute("href");
```

Edit: To open the stored link,

```
driver.get(linkToOpen);
```

this will open the link in the same tab.

Comment: Thanks! How can I open the stored link instead of clicking the button to go to the link?